# Firebase Analytics (Android): events seen in Logcat log but not in Firebase console

Tags: java, android, analytics, firebase-analytics

I added Firebase Analytics to my Android project. Most of the stats are well recorded in the console :
- the global dashboard is ok
- the standard events appear in the events tab

but...my custom events are not displayed in the console.

Moreover, I see my events in adb and seems that everything is ok. For example:

```
Logging event (FE): select_content, Bundle[{item_name=foldersactivity_oncreate, firebase_event_origin(_o)=app}]
```

Here is my code :

```
  public static void trackWithFirebase(String name)
        {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);        
MyApp.mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);

        }
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand my mistake. All the params are recorder under the SELECT_CONTENT root event (which is displayed as "select_content" in the console). I don't see right now how to see the content of the bundles in the console. But at least I understand what is going on.